# Conversion of Dict object into a list of dict object

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following dict structure

```
d = {'Attributes': {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)',
                    'First': 'Art (40.0%)',
                    'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)',
                    'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)',
                    'Third': 'per (20.67%)'}}
```

Need to convert into the following structure list of dictionary items

```
 [   0: {'First': 'Art (40.0%)'},
     1: {'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)'},
     2: {'Third': 'per (20.67%)'},
     3: {'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)'},
     4: {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)'}
 ]
```

Comment: The output you want is a syntax error.

Comment: I need to convert the dict object into a list of key value items, there are fourth twice it should be fith you are right

Comment: So `(key, value)` tuples, then?

Comment: lists don't have key, values. They have elements. Do you mean something like `[{'First': 'Art (40.0%)'}, {'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)'}, ...]` or `[(0, {'First': 'Art (40.0%)'}), (2, {'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)'}), ...]`?

Comment: please  post let me check that, please post both the answers thanks

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham No. You post a valid output first, we're not going to guess what you want. You need to help us to help you.

Comment: Are you trying to sort these items on the percentage in the value, or the meaning of the key?

Comment: Sorting can be secondary first i need the data in the list of key value  pairs inside the list

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham, Please [edit your quest](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50970824/edit) to include  **valid Python syntax** as desired output.

Comment: No percentage sorting, I need to put them in the order into the list

Comment: @FHTMitchell, should we use format strings: to form the structure  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops

Comment: Look at `list(d['Attributes'].items())`.  How does that compare to your desired output?

Comment: In what order? Just saying 'in order' doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I am checking it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear and your desired output is not valid Python. I assume you want a list of dictionaries as your desired output. There are a few steps.

1. **Define your order**. Python doesn't know the string "Fourth" should come after "Third".
2. **Apply ordering to dictionary items**. Dictionaries are unordered in Python (unless you are using 3.7+).
3. **Use a comprehension with enumerate** to construct your list result.

Here's a complete example.

```
d = {'Attributes': {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)',
                    'First': 'Art (40.0%)',
                    'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)',
                    'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)',
                    'Third': 'per (20.67%)'}}

order = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'))}

sorter = sorted(d['Attributes'].items(), key=lambda x: order[x[0]])

L = [dict(enumerate({k: v} for k, v in sorter))]

print(L)

[{0: {'First': 'Art (40.0%)'},
  1: {'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)'},
  2: {'Third': 'per (20.67%)'},
  3: {'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)'},
  4: {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)'}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the structure you want as output is not a python `list` format.
Actually, it is not also a dictionary format either.

From your question, I've learned that you want to make a list of dictionaries.

First, make a dictionary element:

```
0: {'First': 'Art (40.0%)'}
```

to

```
{0: {'First': 'Art (40.0%)'}}
```

Then, you will be ready to make a list of a dictionary and your data structure will look like:

```
[   {0: {'First': 'Art (40.0%)'}},
     {1: {'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)'}},
     {2: {'Third': 'per (20.67%)'}},
     {3: {'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)'}},
     {4: {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)'}}
 ]
```

you can check the structure:

```
list =  [   {0: {'First': 'Art (40.0%)'}},
     {1: {'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)'}},
     {2: {'Third': 'per (20.67%)'}},
     {3: {'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)'}},
     {4: {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)'}}
 ]
print(type(a))
print(type(list[0]))
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'dict'>
```

And the code

```
dict_value = {'Attributes': {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)',
                    'First': 'Art (40.0%)',
                    'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)',
                    'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)',
                    'Third': 'per (20.67%)'}}

order = {value: key for key, value in enumerate(('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'))}

sorted_form = sorted(dict_value['Attributes'].items(), key=lambda d: order[d[0]])
final_list = [dict(enumerate({key: value} for key, value in sorted_form))]

print(final_list)
```

produces

```
[{0: {'First': 'Art (40.0%)'}, 1: {'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)'}, 2: {'Third': 'per (20.67%)'}, 3: {'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)'}, 4: {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)'}}]
```

Comment: what if my output just has to be, please let me know 
  [{'First': 'Art (40.0%)'},
  {'Second': 'Nat (21.33%)'},
  {'Third': 'per (20.67%)'},
  {'Fourth': 'Ser (20.0%)'},
  {'Fifth': 'blind (19.33%)'}]

Comment: just change the `final_list` as `final_list = {item[0]:item[1] for item in sorted_form}`